# how to select two attributes at same time

Tags: sql

I am new to sql, I would like to search account id and rule name in my table, but I got this error

```
Expression"AccountID must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in aggregate function".
```

**I added it in count, it seems wrong, how to resolve this problem ?**

This is the query:

```
 SELECT AccountID, RuleName, COUNT(1) as COUNT
        FROM(**)
        WITH (***)
        GROUP BY RuleName;
```

Comment: `WITH` ??? That is not proper SQL.

Comment: On a side note: While `COUNT(1)` is often seen, I don't recommend using it. We count rows with `COUNT(*)`. We count an expression (`COUNT(something)`) when we want to check for nulls and omit them from the count. 1 can never be null, so it makes little sense to use it as the expression in `COUNT`.

Comment: As to your `GROUP BY` clause: `GROUP BY ____` means you want one result row per ____. You group by rule name, but you don't want one result row per rule name. You want one result row per account number and rule name. Hence the clause must be `GROUP BY AccountID, RuleName`.

Comment: Thanks Thorsten, I got your point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error said you need to add `AccountID` as well to `group by`

```
SELECT AccountID, RuleName, COUNT(1) as COUNT
FROM tbl
GROUP BY AccountID, RuleName;
```